# How to get ClassName of active form (may be from another application) on Delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-xe2

How to get ClassName of active form (may be from another application) on Delphi?

It seems `Application.ActiveFormHandle` returns active form of `Application` only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The window handle that you are looking for is, I believe, returned by [`GetForegroundWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633505.aspx).

To get the class name, pass that window handle to the Windows API function [`GetClassName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633582.aspx). Here's a Delphi wrapper to that API function:

```
function GetWindowClassName(Window: HWND): string;
const
  MaxClassNameLength = 257;//256 plus null terminator
var
  Buffer: array [0..MaxClassNameLength-1] of Char;
  len: Integer;
begin
  len := GetClassName(Window, Buffer, Length(Buffer));
  if len=0 then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  SetString(Result, Buffer, len);
end;
```

I used a buffer of length 256 because window class names are not allowed to be longer than that.

Comment: The length of the buffer includes the null terminator. The actual length of the class name can be up to 256 characters not including the null terminator, so you should remove the -1 from the buffer declaration. The return value is the number of characters copied into the buffer, which you can pass to `SetString()` to optimize the string allocation so the RTL does not have to calculate the length you already have.

Comment: @Remy I did wonder whether it was 256 or 257. I couldn't decide from the documentation. And yes, using `SetString` is better. No point throwing away the information returned by `GetClassName`.